# Check Device Orientation in Android

Tags: android, orientation

I want to create a new activity on the orientation change of the device without changing the current activity orientation. Is there any way to do this?

Additional Info:

My total applications default orientation is Portrate. I have to open second activity when the device is in Landscape. But the first activity should be in Portrate
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. Finally I done this by using `SensorEventListener`.

**OnCreate()**

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
```

**Listener**

```
    private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // angle between the magnetic north directio
        // 0=North, 90=East, 180=South, 270=West
        float azimuth = event.values[1];
        // compassView.updateData(azimuth);

        if ((azimuth < 100 && azimuth > 60)
                || (azimuth > -100 && azimuth < -60)) {
            if (EasterVal != 0) {
                if (!Modules.LoanType.equalsIgnoreCase("Ballcash")) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(Buyeroutput.this, Esteregg.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    EasterVal = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            EasterVal = 1;
        }
    }
};

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (sensor != null) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:screenOrienttation="Landscape/Portrate"` in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` for the perticular activity.So that rest of activity will remain in there default view and the perticure activity will force to display in specific view as you mension.

Hope this help you.

Comment: After set the default orientation in AndroidMenifest.xml for the activity, I cant recognize the screen orientation of the activity.

Comment: there is no need to reconize the orientation because your perticuler activity is in either landscape or portrate mode as you have mension in your menifest file.

Comment: see what you have to do is just use `screenOrientiation="Landscape"` attribute for the activity which you want in landscape.Ex. `<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrienttation="Landscape">` like this for the activity which you want in landscape.

Comment: Sorry. Once I set the first activity (which has to open the second ativity while the orientation changes) to portrate. getResources().getConfiguration().orientation not recognizing the orientation change.

Comment: You don't need to do find the orientiation.Just use ScreenOrientiation attribute it will automatically start the activity in landscape mode

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you please explain.

Comment: ok what you are not getting out of that? I had explained it. but still if you don't get then please tell me what you are not getting?

Answer (score 2):

Well of course you can. You just declare in your manifest that your first activity will handle orientation changes. Then add an onConfigurationChanged function that starts your second activity.

Comment: I used onConfigurationChanged. But I have to check the orientation without change the orientation of first activity.

Answer (score 1):

write in Menifest

**for first Activity**

```
  <activity  android:name="firstActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

**for second Activity**

```
   <activity  android:name="secondActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Comment: Once I set the first activity (which has to open the second ativity while the orientation changes) to portrate. getResources().getConfiguration().orientation not recognizing the orientation change.

Comment: Ohh k also we can set runtime setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Answer (score 1):

You could also programmatically detect the current orientation of your activity and run an intent to your second activity whenever your device is in landscape mode. Here is a code to accomplish it:

```
WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
if(d.getWidth() > d.getHeight())
{
    // landscape mode
    Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Can please guide where to call these functions. I want to call this when i change my orientation.

Comment: As I set  android:screenOrientation="portrait" in AndroidMenifest.xml. the onCreate will be called at only once. I want  your function to be called in Landscape. Without changing the activity orientation.

Comment: As I understood you want to start a new activity when you flip your device to landscape mode, is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct. But the current activity should no change the orientation

Comment: But when you flip your device your current activity is killed anyway and new activity starts so what do you mean by saying "current activity should no change the orientation"?

Comment: I wont finish the previous activity. It will be in the back stack.